# How to avoid DISTINCT in a query that joins multiple tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, distinct

I want to avoid using DISTINCT and produce the same result for queries that join multiple tables. 
Without DISTINCT, it produces the same row multiple times.

I already tried looking up how to avoid DISTINCT, but nothing seems to work for me, seemingly because my table is more complicated and joining multiple tables at the same time.

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.COL3, B.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL4, B.COL5 FROM C
INNER JOIN B
ON B.COL1 = C.COL1 
INNER JOIN A
ON B.COL2 = A.COL2
ORDER BY C.COL3 ASC;
```

I know I have to use `GROUP BY` somehow, but I just can't wrap my head around it...

Comment: If your answer requires it then it's perfectly fine to use it!  Using `GROUP BY` to achieve the same purpose gains you nothing other than confusing semantics (`GROUP BY` is more often associated with aggregations).

What's your problem with it?  What are your inputs and requirements?

Comment: I have to use ```GROUP BY``` because if I use ```DISTINCT```, I won't be able to use the query in another query as a subquery. It just seems to ignore the ```DISTINCT``` keyword if I use it as a subquery; weird, I know. I want to use a SUM function over this subquery and *perhaps* another GROUP BY

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  Can you explain more about the problem and actual SQL?

Comment: I want to transform my query into 

```SELECT DISTINCT C.COL3, A.COL2,  SUM(B.COL5) FROM C
INNER JOIN B
ON B.COL1 = C.COL1 
INNER JOIN A
ON B.COL2 = A.COL2
GROUP BY C.COL3, A.COL2
ORDER BY C.COL3 ASC;```

but doing this simply discards my previous ```DISTINCT``` keyword and counts duplicates as well for some reason (most likely because I'm missing something)

Comment: Note*: by counts duplicates as well, I mean it accounts duplicate rows to the SUM as well.

Comment: Your `DISTINCT` is redundant here as you have a `GROUP BY`.  How will the rows be duplicated?

Comment: The rows are duplicated because I only SELECT ```C.COL3```, ```A.COL2``` and the ```SUM``` and use ```GROUP BY``` only for them (because my final query should only show ```C.COL3``` and ```A.COL2```. The final query is the one I have written in the comment above and it somehow takes some rows multiple times. I'm just as confused as you, plus I'm fairly new to SQL.

Comment: You need to start from first principles describing your problem.  So take your first query and remove any DISTINCT, ORDER by etc.  From that data set, what exactly is it you want to get out?

Comment: https://justpaste.it/59pws 

This fully clarifies what I want, sorry for being so messy - it's been a long day, but I hugely appreciate your help

Comment: https://justpaste.it/3ox4g And this is what we have so far gets me. Since the sum is greater than it should be, it's only fair to assume it's counting duplicates too, isn't it?

Comment: I've answered your question according to your comments but you still don't make it clear why you think the DISTINCT is wrong.

Comment: I thought the DISTINCT was wrong because I didn't see how I could extract all the columns and still group only by 2 columns at the same time. 

You made a subquery with all the columns and my brain just couldn't have thought about that if it weren't for you :)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just group by all the columns (without having ay aggregation):

```
SELECT
   C.COL3, B.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL4, B.COL5
FROM C
JOIN B ON B.COL1 = C.COL1 
JOIN A ON B.COL2 = A.COL2
GROUP BY C.COL3, B.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL4, B.COL5 -- group by all selected columns
ORDER BY C.COL3 ASC
```

---

If you then wanted to aggregate over the de-duped rows of the above query, use it as a subquery. For example, to `SUM(B.COL5)` of the de-duped rows:

```
SELECT
    COL3, COL1, COL2, COL4, SUM(COL5)
FROM (
    SELECT
       C.COL3, B.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL4, B.COL5
    FROM C
    JOIN B ON B.COL1 = C.COL1 
    JOIN A ON B.COL2 = A.COL2
    GROUP BY C.COL3, B.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL4, B.COL5
) deduped
GROUP BY COL3, COL1, COL2, COL4
ORDER BY COL3 ASC
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine and answers my question well, but if I wanted to GROUP BY ```C.COL3``` and ```A.COL2``` and ```SUM``` up ```B.COL5```, how would I do that? 

I took your query, deleted ```B.COL1```, ```A.COL4``` from the ```SELECT``` and ```GROUP BY``` expressions and I added ```SUM``` to ```B.COL5```. This still counts duplicates. How can I further modify this to not take duplicates for the ```SUM```? Thank you for your answer and interest :)

Comment: This does exactly the same as `DISTINCT` which presumably is not what he wants

Comment: @Eric see edited answer - I think that's what you were asking for

Comment: ```SELECT
    deduped.COL3, deduped.COL2, SUM(deduped.COL5)
FROM (
    SELECT
       C.COL3, B.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL4, B.COL5
    FROM C
    JOIN B ON B.COL1 = C.COL1 
    JOIN A ON B.COL2 = A.COL2
    GROUP BY C.COL3, B.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL4, B.COL5
) deduped
GROUP BY deduped.COL3, deduped.COL2
ORDER BY COL3 ASC```

This still takes duplicates into consideration. I'm definitely missing something here, aren't I? :( 

Thanks for bearing with me anyway

Comment: https://justpaste.it/59pws 

This fully clarifies what I want, sorry for being so messy - it's been a long day, but I hugely appreciate your help

Comment: https://justpaste.it/3ox4g And this is what we have so far gets me. Since the sum is greater than it should be, it's only fair to assume it's counting duplicates too, isn't it?

Comment: @eric either don't select col4 or col5 anywhere in the query, or further wrap the query to de-dupe the de-dupe: `select col3, col2, sum(col5) from (select col3, col2, col5 from (<my initial query>) ) dededuped group by col3, col2`

Comment: That really might work too, I wish I could give you credit for that.

However, @LoztInSpace made an answer and I marked that as correct because it works :) 

Thank you very much!

Comment: @Eric since the other answer is a copy of mine and my answer pre-dates the other by an hour, it is customary to give credit to the original work. Interestingly, the other answer doesn't actually answer the question as stated, even though it "solves your problem", you didn't ask about "your problem"

Comment: @Bohemian Oops, I'm sorry about that! :) I marked your answer as correct now!

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting multiple duplicate rows of the same data if you do not use DISTINCT? If so, this query worked for me when I was joining multiple asp net tables in order to show the user info, plus the roles within the site they are assigned to. Hopefully this can help you.

```
SELECT AspNetUsers.Id, AspNetRoles.Name as SiteRole,
AspNetRoles.ID as RoleID, AspNetUsers.UserName, 
AspNetUsers.Email FROM AspNetUserRoles INNER JOIN
AspNetUsers ON AspNetUserRoles.UserId = AspNetUsers.Id INNER JOIN
AspNetRoles ON AspNetUserRoles.RoleId = AspNetRoles.Id
```

Comment: Yes, I am getting duplicate rows of the same data if I do not use ```DISTINCT```. If I apply your pattern to my code, I get duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` partition by [column you want to be distinct].

```
select * 
    from (select c.col3, b.col1, a.col2, a.col4, b.col5
        , row_number() over (partition by c.col1 order by c.col3) as rn
    from c
    inner join b on b.col1 = c.col1
    inner join a on a.col2 = b.col2) t1
where t1.rn = 1
order by t1.col3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COL3, COL1, SUM(COL5)
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT C.COL3, B.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL4, B.COL5 FROM C
INNER JOIN B
ON B.COL1 = C.COL1 
INNER JOIN A
ON B.COL2 = A.COL2
) X
GROUP BY COL3, COL1
ORDER BY COL3, COL1
```